# Однокоренные слова

Tags: синтаксис, однокоренные-слова

Какие существуют однокоренные слова к слову "рысью" (бежать)? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Интересный вопрос! Это, во-первых, исходное существительное *рысь* (животное) вкупе с прилагательным *рысий*.
Во-вторых, существительное *рысь* со значением 'быстрый аллюр, средний между галопом и шагом': *перевести коня с галопа на рысь*.
И, в-третьих, слова, образованные уже него: *рысистый, рысистость, рысак, рысачок, рысачий*.
Восьми слов хватит? :)